Failed to finish transaction: [Error: Google is indicating that we have some issue connecting to payment.]
I am building a react native app and using react-native-iap package for integrating IAP and subscriptions.
Here is my code:
const PurchaseIAP = () => {

  const acknowledgePurchase = useCallback(async purchase => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        if (purchase && !purchase.isAcknowledgedAndroid) {
          if (!purchase.purchaseToken) {
            throw new Error('Purchase token is missing');
          }
          await acknowledgePurchaseAndroid({token: purchase.purchaseToken});
        } else {
          console.log(
            'Purchase already acknowledged or invalid purchase object:',
            purchase,
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('Failed to acknowledge purchase:', error);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const handlePurchaseUpdate = useCallback(
    async purchase => {
      console.log('Purchase update received:', purchase);
      const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
      if (receipt) {
        try {
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            await acknowledgePurchase(purchase);
          }
          console.log('Purchase updated and acknowledged:', purchase);
          const ackResult = await finishTransaction({
            purchase,
            isConsumable: true,
          });
          console.log('Transaction finished:', ackResult);
          setLoading(true);
          Alert.alert('Purchase Successful', 'Thank you for your purchase!', [
            {
              text: 'OK',
              onPress: () => {
                setLoading(false);
                setTransactionFinished(true);
              },
            },
          ]);
        } catch (ackErr) {
          console.warn('Failed to finish transaction:', ackErr);
          setTransactionFinished(false);
          Alert.alert('Transaction Error', 'Failed to complete transaction.');
        }
      } else {
        console.warn('Transaction receipt is missing:', purchase);
      }
    },
    [acknowledgePurchase],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const purchaseUpdateSubscription =
      purchaseUpdatedListener(handlePurchaseUpdate);

    return () => {
      if (purchaseUpdateSubscription) {
        purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
      }
    };
  }, [handlePurchaseUpdate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeIAP = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await initConnection();
        if (result) {
          setIsIapReady(true);
          console.log('IAP connection initialized');
          await getAvailableProductsAndSubscriptions();
          if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            await flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid();
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn('Failed to initialize IAP', err);
        showAlert('IAP Error', 'Failed to initialize in-app purchases.');
      }
    };

    const getAvailableProductsAndSubscriptions = async () => {
      if (getItemsRequest.current) {
        return;
      }

      setLoading(true);
      getItemsRequest.current = true;
      try {
        const productResult = await getProducts({skus: productIds});
        const subscriptionResult = await getSubscriptions({
          skus: subscriptionIds,
        });
        setProducts([...productResult, ...subscriptionResult]);
        console.log('Products:', productResult);
        console.log('Subscriptions:', subscriptionResult);
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn('Failed to get products or subscriptions', err);
        console.log(
          'Error',
          'Failed to fetch product or subscription details.',
        );
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
        getItemsRequest.current = false;
      }
    };

    initializeIAP();

    const purchaseErrorSubscription = purchaseErrorListener(purchaseError => {
      console.log('Purchase error', purchaseError);
      if (!alertVisible) {
        showAlert('Purchase Error', purchaseError.message);
      }
      setAlertVisible(false);
      setTransactionFinished(false);
      // Handle error
    });

    return () => {
      if (purchaseErrorSubscription) {
        purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
      }
      endConnection();
    };
  }, [showAlert, alertVisible, navigation, token]);

  const handlePurchase = async product => {
    if (!isIapReady) {
      if (!alertVisible) {
        showAlert('IAP not ready', 'Please wait for IAP to initialize.');
      }
      return;
    }
    if (products.length === 0) {
      if (!alertVisible) {
        showAlert('No Products', 'No products available for purchase.');
      }
      return;
    }

    try {
      if (product.productType === 'subs' && Platform.OS === 'android') {
        // console.log('Attempting to purchase subscription:', product.productId);
        const offerToken = getOfferToken(product);
        if (!offerToken) {
          if (!alertVisible) {
            showAlert(
              'Offer Token Missing',
              'No valid offer token found for this SKU.',
            );
          }
          return;
        }
        console.log('productId', product.productId);
        console.log('offerToken', offerToken);
        await subscribe(product.productId, offerToken);
      } else {
        await makePurchase(product.productId);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn('Purchase Failed', err);
      if (!alertVisible) {
        showAlert('Purchase failed', err.message);
      }
    }
  };

  const makePurchase = async sku => {
    let request;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      request = {
        skus: [sku],
        obfuscatedAccountIdAndroid: token,
      };
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      request = {
        sku: sku,
        appAccountToken: token,
      };
    }

    console.log('purchase request 209', request);
    try {
      const purchase = await requestPurchase(request);
      console.log('Purchase Result:', purchase);
      if (!alertVisible) {
        showAlert('Purchase Successful', 'Thank you for your purchase!');
      }
      setTransactionFinished(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn('Purchase Failed', err);
      setAlertVisible(false);
      if (err.code !== 'E_USER_CANCELLED') {
        Alert.alert('Purchase failed', err.message);
        setAlertVisible(false);
      } else {
        console.log('Purchase error', err);
      }
    }
  };

  const subscribe = async (sku, offerToken) => {
    try {
      let subscriptionRequest;
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        subscriptionRequest = {
          sku,
          ...(offerToken && {subscriptionOffers: [{sku, offerToken}]}),
          obfuscatedAccountIdAndroid: token,
        };
      } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        subscriptionRequest = {
          sku,
          ...(offerToken && {subscriptionOffers: [{sku, offerToken}]}),
          appAccountToken: token,
        };
      }
      console.log('Subscription Request:', subscriptionRequest);

      const purchase = await requestSubscription(subscriptionRequest);
      console.log('Subscription Purchase Result:', purchase);
      if (!alertVisible) {
        showAlert('Subscription Successful', 'Thank you for subscribing!');
      }
      setTransactionFinished(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn('Purchase Failed', err);
      console.error('Error details:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      console.error('Error code:', err.code);
      console.error('Error message:', err.message);
      setAlertVisible(false);

      if (err.code !== 'E_USER_CANCELLED') {
        Alert.alert('Purchase failed', `${err.message}\nCode: ${err.code}`);
      } else {
        console.log('User cancelled the purchase', err);
      }
    }
  };

 WARN  Failed to finish transaction: [Error: Google is indicating that we have some issue connecting to payment.]
and also I am acknowledging purchase still I am getting acknowledged purchase = false.
\"acknowledged\":false
I tried googling complete method from initConnection IAP to completing transaction, but I don't know where I am lacking and what causing error.

This test purchase was cancelled because it was not acknowledged. You should ensure that all purchases are acknowledged so that they are not subject to refunds. For more information, see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process.
